# Typescript object with keys of specific type (and working intellisense)

Tags: typescript, types, intellisense

I'm trying to type an object so that its' keys are all of a specific type, but in such a way that I still get intellisense when I access the the main object.

```
interface ObjectWithKeysOf<T>
{
    [key: string]: T;
}

const TEST: ObjectWithKeysOf<number> =
{
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2
};
```

Given the above, I hoped that the following would work, but it doesn't.  Intellisense doesn't suggest `prop1` as a property, and the code fails to compile.

```
const aNumber = TEST.prop1;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Worth noting that there's a different data structure that is possibly more applicable here, namely a map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `satisfies` operator — [introduced in TypeScript v`4.9`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#satisfies) — to constrain a type while preserving its specifics (including IntelliSense autocompletion):

Try it out in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.9.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQNswA4CcRcBGALhmIBoscCiAmc+6gXxggEMoBLCAM26IYAJXih8AEwA80fNzABzSjDABXALYAjePgB8AbgwYE0AHR0ShnAHprAPQD8Rk1HOFc9K9luPniVxYAzPow1gBUNDgAfjExGAAK7jpQAJ4wAORB6TASIEJgILDwAB68sOBwKbjwGWh47mQqGtr4IRaMTVo6ISzppjAAItwSMCkgqjDq8BxgGRbE6Q4AFPQArKvEAJQwYdYYQA):

```ts
const test = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
} satisfies Record<string, number>;

test.prop1;
   //^? (property) prop1: number

test.prop2;
   //^? (property) prop2: number

test.prop3; /*
     ~~~~~
Property 'prop3' does not exist on type '{ prop1: number; prop2: number; }'. Did you mean 'prop1'?(2551) */
```

---

The same example, but combined with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.9.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQNswA4CcRcBGALhmIBoscCiAmc+6gXxgEMIZRJYJ2oASwgAzQYhgAleKHwATADzR8gsAHNKMMAFcAtgCN4+AHwBuDBgTQAdHRLmcAekcA9APwWrUW4Vz0H2M7unojedgDMpjCOAFQ0OAB+SUkYAAq+RlAAnjAA5BG5MHIgEmAgsPAAHsKw4HBZuPB5aDD48OzFYAA2OXZkFFFtHeA9eL6MMP4wLLnWMAAignIwWSDaMLrtYHl9uW4AFPQArEfEAJQwMY4YQA)

```ts
const test = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
} as const satisfies Record<string, number>;

test.prop1;
   //^? (property) prop1: 1

test.prop2;
   //^? (property) prop2: 2

test.prop3; /*
     ~~~~~
Property 'prop3' does not exist on type '{ readonly prop1: 1; readonly prop2: 2; }'. Did you mean 'prop1'?(2551) */
```

---

See also the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

Comment: Perfect!  Now I just need Visual Studio 2022 to use TypeScript 4.9...